# styling 2 text styles in one DIV, including list

Tags: html, css, text, styling

I want the footer of my site to hold 2 links: one to the cookies policy and one to the privacy policy (to the bottom right of the footer).

I also want it to include the address of the business (the bottom left of the footer), the links have already been formatted using this CSS (and show as I want them to):

```
  a:link { color: #ff8132; text-decoration: none }
  a:active { color: #79888c; font-weight: bold }
  a:visited { color:#ff8132; text-decoration: none }
  a:hover { color: #404f55;  text-decoration: underline}
```

but when I try to format the address using the this CSS:

```
  #footer {
margin:auto;
height: 100px;
width:60%;
background-color: #101f3e;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-color: #EF0E12;
}
```

It doesn't work?

The HTML I have for it:

```
  <div id= "footer">
  The Dry Otter</br>
  Headingley Lane</br>
  Leeds</br>
  LS6 1BL
  <a href="ottercookies.php">Cookie Policy</a>
  <a href="otterprivacy.php">Privacy Policy</a>


 </div>
```

any ideas? Please bare in mind I'm quite new to coding!

thank you!

Comment: It's `color` not `font-color`

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The font-family? The background color? If the color of the text is not there, essentially is what @Adrift says